# How to hide an element from an array with showFields

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Hello I am new in the world of apostrophe and I have a question as to whether an element of an array could be hidden with showFields if summoned from outside.

```
  module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'One Column',


  addFields: [
    {
      type: 'select',
      name: 'columnType',
      label: ' How many type columns do you want?',
      choices: [
      {
        label: '1',
        value: '1',

        showFields: [ ...]
      },
    },


    {
      name: 'columns',
      label: 'Column',
      type: 'array',
      titleField: 'array',
      schema: [ 

        {
          type: 'select',
          name: 'column1',
          label: 'size column 1',

          choices: [
            {label: '',value: '',},
            {label: '1',value: '-1',},
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

It would be possible to hide the element 'column1'. If you invoke from the 'columnType' attribute from showfiel?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `showFields` cannot access fields that are nested in an array schema. You could, however, use showFields to show and hide two separate array fields with different schemas, and use the appropriate data depending on the selected one.